# Instruments Time Profiler: What does <Call stack limit reached> mean? Can I control the limit?

Tags: recursion, profiling, instruments, stack-trace

[image: Instruments screenshot showing <Call stack limit reached>]

When my program is executing a deeply recursive algorithm, the Time Profiler in Instruments creates what looks like a new entry point function called `<Call stack limit reached>`.  I guess this means that Time Profiler has some limit when back-tracing the current stack when it samples.

Can I control this limit?  If so, how?

**Edit**

I've tried the `Preferences->DTrace->Max Backtrace Depth` setting but it appears to have no effect.

Here is a short program with deep recursion that gets to the defined depth an spends a while there:

```
#define RECURSION_DEPTH 200

void recurse( unsigned const depth )
{
    if( RECURSION_DEPTH == depth ) for( unsigned i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i );
    else recurse( depth + 1 );
}

int main()
{
    recurse( 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

When I Time Profile this program, I continue to see the `<Call stack limit reached>` phenomenon even if I set the DTrace preference to a number much greater than 200.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the maximum call stack depth from Instruments' preferences, in the DTrace section. The initial call stack limit is 128.

[image]

Comment: This setting appears to have no effect for me.  See my edits to the question for more information.

Comment: I don't know of any other way to set the maximum call stack depth. Since you said your code has deep recursion, the only other thing I can suggest is to select the Flatten Recursion checkbox in the Call Tree section.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that option only changes the way the gathered information is collected.  The first part of the call stack has already been thrown away during sampling.